# Flutter (the doctor check crashed)

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Flutter (the doctor check crashed)
X Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know
about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
X Exception: Cannot find the executable for `where`. This can happen if the System32 folder (e.g.
C:\Windows\System32 ) is removed from the PATH environment variable. Ensure that this is present and then try
again after restarting the terminal and/or IDE.

research, try my best

Comment: what does this have to do with VS Code?